# InvalidArgumentError: Cannot add tensor to the batch: number of elements does not match. Shapes are: [tensor]: [4], [batch]: [5] [Op:IteratorGetNext]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, ocr

Task:
Keras captcha ocr model training.

Problem:
I am trying to print CAPTCHAS from my validation set, but doing so is causing the following error

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-df1fce607804> in <module>()
      1 
      2 #_, ax = plt.subplots(1, 4, figsize=(10, 5))
----> 3 for batch in validation_dataset.take(1):
      4     images = batch["image"]
      5     labels = batch["label"]

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   7105 def raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name):
   7106   e.message += (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
-> 7107   raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   7108 
   7109 

InvalidArgumentError: Cannot add tensor to the batch: number of elements does not match. Shapes are: [tensor]: [4], [batch]: [5] [Op:IteratorGetNext]
```

The code to print my output, this is what I tried:

```
#_, ax = plt.subplots(1, 4, figsize=(10, 5))
for batch in validation_dataset.take(1):
    images = batch["image"]
    labels = batch["label"]
    for i in range(batch_size):
        img = (images[i] * 255).numpy().astype("uint8")
        label = tf.strings.reduce_join(num_to_char(labels[i])).numpy().decode("utf-8")
        plt.title(label)
        plt.imshow(img[:, :, 0].T, cmap="gray")
        plt.show()
```

For this task, i tried setting batch size 1, but i want to train my model with higher batch size
my batch size = 16

```
# Mapping integers back to original characters
num_to_char = layers.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=char_to_num.get_vocabulary(), mask_token=None, invert=True
)
```

This is the code taken from tensorflow datasets docs to convert data to dataset type in tf
Creating Dataset objects

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train]))
train_dataset = (
    train_dataset.map(
        encode_single_sample, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE
    )
    .batch(batch_size)
    .prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE).repeat(10)
)

validation_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_valid, y_valid]))
validation_dataset = (
    validation_dataset.map(
        encode_single_sample, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE
    )
    .batch(batch_size)
    .prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
)
```

This code does reading the image and preprocessing the image to bring all the images to uniform shape
Function encode single sample

```
def encode_single_sample(img_path, label):
    # 1. Read image
    img = tf.io.read_file(img_path)
    # 2. Decode and convert to grayscale
    img = tf.io.decode_png(img, channels=3)
    # 3. Convert to float32 in [0, 1] range
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
    # 4. Resize to the desired size
    img = tf.image.resize(img, [img_height, img_width])
    # 5. Transpose the image because we want the time
    # dimension to correspond to the width of the image.
    img = tf.transpose(img, perm=[1, 0, 2])
    # 6. Map the characters in label to numbers
    label = char_to_num(tf.strings.unicode_split(label, input_encoding="UTF-8"))
    # 7. Return a dict as our model is expecting two inputs
    return {"image": img, "label": label}
```

Edits:
Regarding the data:
This is a sample from the [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PfJza03OfznMKp0i6XnJTWUmHGIXJHhb/view?usp=sharing). Its similar to the  [keras ocr example](https://keras.io/examples/vision/captcha_ocr/)  dataset. Although the image sizes vary, although very less variability in the captcha patterns. It maintains 5 length words with 1 or two numbers in between. Words are always in uppercase.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete running example based on your dataset running in Google Colab:

```
!pip install unrar
!unrar x /content/captcha_caps.rar

import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

data_dir = Path("/content/captcha_caps/")

images = sorted(list(map(str, list(data_dir.glob("*.PNG")))))
labels = [img.split(os.path.sep)[-1].split(".PNG")[0] for img in images]
characters = set(char for label in labels for char in label)

print("Number of images found: ", len(images))
print("Number of labels found: ", len(labels))
print("Number of unique characters: ", len(characters))
print("Characters present: ", characters)

batch_size = 16

img_width = 200
img_height = 50

downsample_factor = 4

max_length = max([len(label) for label in labels])
char_to_num = layers.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=list(characters), mask_token=None
)

num_to_char = layers.StringLookup(
    vocabulary=char_to_num.get_vocabulary(), mask_token=None, invert=True
)

def split_data(images, labels, train_size=0.9, shuffle=True):
    size = len(images)
    indices = np.arange(size)
    if shuffle:
        np.random.shuffle(indices)
    train_samples = int(size * train_size)
    x_train, y_train = images[indices[:train_samples]], labels[indices[:train_samples]]
    x_valid, y_valid = images[indices[train_samples:]], labels[indices[train_samples:]]
    return x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid

x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = split_data(np.array(images), np.array(labels))


def encode_single_sample(img_path, label):
    img = tf.io.read_file(img_path)
    img = tf.io.decode_png(img, channels=1)
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
    img = tf.image.resize(img, [img_height, img_width])
    img = tf.transpose(img, perm=[1, 0, 2])
    label = char_to_num(tf.strings.unicode_split(label, input_encoding="UTF-8"))
    return {"image": img, "label": label}

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
train_dataset = (
    train_dataset.map(
        encode_single_sample, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE
    )
    .batch(batch_size)
    .prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE).repeat(10)
)

validation_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_valid, y_valid))
validation_dataset = (
    validation_dataset.map(
        encode_single_sample, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE
    )
    .batch(batch_size)
    .prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
)

_, ax = plt.subplots(4, 4, figsize=(10, 5))
for batch in validation_dataset.take(1):
    images = batch["image"]
    labels = batch["label"]
    for i in range(16):
        img = (images[i] * 255).numpy().astype("uint8")
        label = tf.strings.reduce_join(num_to_char(labels[i])).numpy().decode("utf-8")
        ax[i // 4, i % 4].imshow(img[:, :, 0].T, cmap="gray")
        ax[i // 4, i % 4].set_title(label)
        ax[i // 4, i % 4].axis("off")
plt.show()
```

```
Requirement already satisfied: unrar in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (0.4)

UNRAR 5.50 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2017 Alexander Roshal


Extracting from /content/captcha_caps.rar

Creating    captcha caps                                              OK
Extracting  captcha caps/24VCZ.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/26SGX.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/2HC5E.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/2NDXL.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/2NUEH.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/2QX4B.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/2V78Y.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/2Z45Y.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/2Z9R2.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/32HZA.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/38JKT.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/39EZ4.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/3GJ85.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/3R2JE.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/3RU4C.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/3TPFA.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/3TVAC.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/44U8C.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/452LV.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/4E4P8.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/4E5HX.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/4FVS7.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/4GJCC.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/4QQJD.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/4TH2K.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/4TN2L.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/4YBT5.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/4ZLHE.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/556F5.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/55DT5.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/5CEZD.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/5CQ39.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/5FZUR.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/5H7F4.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/5K4TY.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/5N2KC.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/5P6B4.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/5R728.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/5S9E7.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/5VRRV.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/5VZHL.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/5YVYG.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/63P4N.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/65DQ7.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/66JUU.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/69ZQ3.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/6B655.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/6GBFG.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/6K27H.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/6R7G5.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/6VFYG.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/6X8AJ.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/6ZNJP.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/73ZK2.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/74FPR.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/7C46N.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/7C48B.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/7JVBT.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/7NVS8.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/7REZP.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/7RHSQ.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/7RTT2.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/7VV9J.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/82JNK.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/83JKQ.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/89RGK.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/8A2D7.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/8ENGQ.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/8K5KS.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/95BDX.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/963D9.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/9878H.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/99G9R.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/99RJ8.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/9CKGT.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/9DK36.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/9E3FU.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/9EZCJ.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/9HS3T.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/9J59G.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/9JXEJ.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/9TBBF.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/9TYDP.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/9YEY2.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/A6TC6.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/ADB8Y.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/AERBR.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/AG43G.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/ALX5Q.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/AP6EJ.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/AUFH4.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/AVAYP.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/AX2QR.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/AZS3U.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/B6ZYP.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/B8YTF.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/BEGC2.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/BQFXZ.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/BQSB2.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/BT5CN.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/BYJL9.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/BZYB7.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/C2EFS.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/C3T9L.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/C8C26.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/CACQC.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/CBXJY.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/CE6S8.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/CEFCR.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/CEPQV.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/CF3V8.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/CFR3R.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/CKEQK.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/CUD8R.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/D2ZSU.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/D56EX.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/DBAAX.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/DC2AV.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/DDZRZ.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/DF266.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/DGLYX.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/DNQ8C.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/DPQCC.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/DUU3R.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/DY935.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/DYE9U.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/E6RVE.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/E7B47.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/EB975.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/EHQVT.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/EJB7K.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/EJEUJ.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/EN3SG.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/EQP2Q.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/ESLUT.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/ET497.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/F2GTJ.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/F32UK.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/F8B56.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/FEQRA.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/FF5AZ.png                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/FGBBV.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/FN4XQ.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/FUHZJ.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/FZBZB.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/G3C7R.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/G3H2V.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/G5A9V.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/G9CLN.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/GAGZG.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/GCRFA.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/GF59Q.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/GGFJH.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/GHNPE.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/GKGQ5.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/GLNPR.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/GRKU3.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/GXGEA.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/H2JTQ.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/HAF8J.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/HDK86.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/HLG6G.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/HQEFG.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/HUG3K.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/HZBJ9.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/J38T7.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/J3DG2.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/J5PE7.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/J72PD.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/J8E5Z.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/JC5YF.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/JFEJ5.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/JGXV6.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/K2K9D.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/K4GBD.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/K5QCD.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/K6U7U.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/KCXAC.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/KFBTD.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/KG4HH.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/KHZE4.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/KSJ4A.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/KZ62P.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/L345J.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/L36HP.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/L37HK.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/L9EG2.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/L9H4D.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/LA4P7.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/LBNXN.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/LJ6PC.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/LJ7DT.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/LVRKL.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/LXFBT.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/N52PE.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/N8ZFS.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/NBHG7.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/NGGQ.PNG                                     OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/NHRGB.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/NKJX4.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/NPPPD.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/NU4KH.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/NX7BX.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/P2K69.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/PFHLR.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/PTFPU.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/PV6YU.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/Q4KXA.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/Q6L72.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/Q7HNQ.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/Q8A2V.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/QC7TD.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/QEYHL.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/QHHKX.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/QRRE2.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/QU3JN.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/QURPC.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/QZR3Z.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/R27UF.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/R38UE.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/R3UVK.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/RDE9N.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/RJUNG.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/RJYRY.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/RLKT2.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/RLL8T.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/RLTV6.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/RQ2QT.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/RQZST.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/RU5HH.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/RZFFE.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/S2Y25.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/SG9EL.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/SHRTS.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/SJ6KJ.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/SPHR4.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/SQ7S2.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/SQDUP.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/SVYGE.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/T3HA6.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/T49RZ.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/TJ6DE.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/TNVRU.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/TR9L8.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/TTBYT.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/TUJZK.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/TVAKL.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/U554X.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/U7SKY.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/U8U4N.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/UDB3Z.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/UDD86.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/UDTQS.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/UHB6B.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/UKSL7.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/UP88V.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/URCF5.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/URKGY.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/URQ7D.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/UTYPV.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/UYY55.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/V99ZG.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/VB93G.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/VX43Z.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/VYLHE.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/X9PJE.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/XC93Q.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/XETJ6.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/XGHYS.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/XGSHP.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/XH7NL.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/XHYGL.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/XPQ6V.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/XTC2K.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/XVFC7.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/XY364.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/Y2KFQ.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/Y5HRR.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/Y9R52.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/YC6TY.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/YE6KN.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/YGNG.PNG                                     OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/YJ433.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/YJPSF.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/YL647.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/YNDAP.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/YPJAT.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/YTZLF.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/YU63S.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/YVX5X.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/YXK3G.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/YYGQ2.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/Z3EQP.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/Z79JR.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/ZBJHX.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/ZCUJB.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/ZEEBR.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/ZENDD.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/ZQPTE.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/ZYHPX.PNG                                    OK 
Extracting  captcha caps/ZYJ6X.PNG                                    OK 
All OK
Number of images found:  300
Number of labels found:  300
Number of unique characters:  30
Characters present:  {'9', 'A', '6', 'Y', '2', 'J', '3', 'F', 'C', 'X', 'D', 'N', 'V', '4', '5', 'K', 'Z', '7', 'P', 'L', 'H', 'T', 'Q', 'E', 'U', '8', 'S', 'G', 'R', 'B'}
```

[image]

Comment: square brackets after x_train were corrected. channels set to 1. Error still occurs. I have shared the data in the edit of this post.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: What exactly was the issue that was resolved here?

Comment: @AloneTogether could you please tell what `char_to_num(tf.strings.unicode_split(label, input_encoding="UTF-8"))` does really?

Comment: @SIslam sure.. do you know what a `StringLookup` layer is?

Comment: `tf.strings.unicode_split` splits a string into characters and these characters are sent to `char_to_num`, which is maps characters to unique integers. Does that make sense? @SIslam